# Routing error on NavigationMixin logout action

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, navigation, lwr, logout

I am developing an Experience cloud site with an LWR template. I am trying to create a logout button using the standard code for it:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: "comm__loginPage",
    attributes: {
      actionName: 'logout'
    }
});
```

But when this part is executed I receive this routing error:

```
A URL cannot be created to navigate to route "{"type":"comm__loginPage","attributes":{"actionName":"logout"}}"
```

I also tried to logout using `/secur/logout.jsp` URL but I redirects me to login.salesforce.com page and not the login page for my experience site

Does anyone has any thoughts how this can be fixed or any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

For my LWR site, we were also unable to leverage the NavigationMixin for this standard logout URL. In different scenarios we have either manually included
an 'a href="/secur/logout.jsp"' element, or when needed to keep a consistent navigation menu we have a hidden 'a href="/secur/logout.jsp"' element that we call ".click()" on using an event handler.

Hope that helps you... FYI that worked fine until just recently when we started seeing "/s" appended to the beginning for some reason. Not sure if this is related to Summer '23 or some other update, but if anyone has an idea what introduced that change I'd love to know.